# How do I display a caption with an enlarged image?

Tags: jquery, html

I was wondering if there was a way to display a caption after my image has been englarged in jQuery. Here is my code to increase the size. I would like to increase the size as it is being done and then fade in a gray background and display a caption. Thanks. 
Code:

```
window.onload = function() {
  $("img.index").each(function() {
    $.data(this, 'size', { width: $(this).width(), height: $(this).height() });
  }).hover(function() {
    $(this).stop().animate({ height: $.data(this,'size').height*1.5, 
    width: $.data(this,'size').width*1.5 });
  }, function() {
    $(this).stop().animate({ height: $.data(this,'size').height, 
    width: $.data(this,'size').width });
  });
};
```

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Comment: I have tried the gridHover as well as multiple searches. I think its more a matter that I am only a beginner in jQuery rather than an advanced user. This is what I have been trying last. http://notlaura.com/show-title-hovering-image/

Comment: So what's the issue with your code? That link is a functioning demo you can download and apply to your own work.

Comment: just create an empty div, and then add text to it????  http://jsfiddle.net/RJg6L/   like this?

Answer (score 1):

The jQuery `animate` function has a property for a complete-callback. Use that to show whatever you want after the animation is done:

```
$(this).stop().animate(
    {
        height: $.data(this,'size').height, 
        width: $.data(this,'size').width
    },
    function() {
        $('#the-caption').show();
    }
);
```

See: http://api.jquery.com/animate/

Answer (score 0):

Simply use:

```
$("#your-caption-id").show();
```